# Parsing date strings in java using SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, date-parsing

I am using `SimpleDateFormatter` to parse strings into `Timestamp`

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
```

It correctly parses a date like `2015-08-03T07:45:02.212-0330` but fails with a parse exception for `2015-08-03T07:45:02.212+0330`

Why does it fail? How do I input dates with positive time zones?

Comment: I'm not seeing a parse error for your two date strings.  Could you post a full working/failing snippet to show us how you're using the formatter?  What exception are you getting?

Comment: I just tested it on my machine and it correctly parses input with positive timezone. Can you post your whole code?

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I was able to get it working. The code as you rightly said, has no problem. I was sending the date string in the url query parameter and + was being interpreted as a space. When I replaced + with encoded value %2B , it worked.  BTW, here is the relevant code   public static Timestamp extractTimestamp(String value, SimpleDateFormat sdf) throws ParseException {
    Timestamp ts = null;
    if (null != value & null != sdf) {
      ts = new Timestamp(sdf.parse(value.trim()).getTime());
    }
    return ts;
  }